# Calculate the limit using Taylor expansion

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

I need to calculate the limit using Taylor expansion:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^{1/x}-e}{x}
$$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(1+x)^{\frac1x}=e^{\frac1x \log (1+x)}=e^{\frac1x\left( x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2) \right)}=e^{ 1-\frac{x}{2}+o(x)}$$

$$(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e=e^{ 1-\frac{x}{2}+o(x)}-e=e\left(e^{-\frac{x}{2}+o(x)}-1\right)=e\left(-\frac x2+o(x)\right)$$

$$\frac{(1+x)^{\frac1x}-e}{x}=e\left(-\frac 12+o(1)\right)\to-\frac e2$$